# Going into a PhD in Europe or US

Tags: phd, united-states, europe

I am an International Student perusing a Masters in Actuarial Science in the US. I did my Bachelors here in the US (Actuarial Science), worked for 2 years as an Actuarial Analyst in the US. I am doing my Masters now with emphasis on AI (I could not get into an AI program for Masters due to my circumstances, so this is the closest I could get).

I want to continue with AI and I am looking into a PhD in the N.America or Europe. I am excited about Europe (never been there), but feel N.America will be a safer bet. Which location would be better to do my PhD in, if I am looking at eventually migrating and getting into tech entrepreneurship?

Comment: You are perusing a masters? Or are doing one?

Comment: Safer bet in what sense? In terms of physical health and safety, Europe is certainly a better place to be than the US at the moment.

Comment: Come to Australia.  We are much better than both of your choices.

Comment: Sorry for the awful question format, I just got on here. 
I am current doing a Masters in Actuarial Science, but trying to take introductory AI courses, to shift the emphasis. 
@astronat I am talking in terms of having a better chance of migrating. US migration is just such a mess and I don't know if I want to fester here anymore. The people I met are wonderful, but the system is just very hostile. Out of Europe, Netherlands have peeked my interest, but I hear they tend to hire from Masters not directly.
Would you be kind enough to direct me to unis with AI PhDs?

Comment: @LahiS I know nothing about PhDs in AI or in the Netherlands, so I can't help you there. I'm sure you can find some just by googling. The universities will almost certainly explain their entry requirements on their websites too.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid your question reveals a rather superficial attitude to the matter. You are talking about the whole *continents* as places for "better PhD" and mention "AI" as a field you are interested in. A fairly standard textbook on AI sitting on my shelf is nearly 1200 pages long, so how can one judge a *continent* for being a better place for studying every single topic listed in this book?

You are going to spend several years doing your PhD. So, first go spend at least several days (or, better, weeks) thinking harder what exactly are you interested in. One good starting point would be to think first what you are good at right now. Then, figure out good publications in this area (Google Scholar is your friend) and find out which labs they come from. These labs are the places of your interest, and they might pop up in quite unlikely places (though, granted, in most cases they don't come as a surprise).

Then, of course, there is a question of a job market, but I believe people coming from reputable labs are able to find a job. In any case, this isn't a question of your immediate future.

Comment: A minor nitpick about "continents": to my knowledge, American academia is on the whole fairly homogeneous (unlike European academia which has roughly country-level granularity). If the OP was born and raised in the US, they might assume out of ignorance that academia is homogeneous everywhere. OP's geography comments are IMO much less of a concern than the "PhD on AI" part (which the answer addresses well).

Comment: I am fairly new to AI but so far, my focus has been AI application in Actuarial Science. I don't have a particular area in mind but I am really interested in high volatility, low frequencies edge cases (a comparable e.g: such as extreme weather). I am also interested explaining phenomenon through AI and doing things such as coming up with new performance measures or combining old classical statistical methods to build composite statistical tools to question things. Hope this helps clarify my interests.

Answer (score 1):

You are the best and should be the only person to answer this question. If I were in your shoes I would consider these points.

First, you need to answer the question: what is the objective of you pursuing a PhD degree?

Do you wish to become a professor while trying to get into tech entrepreneurship? Do you wish to invent/discover something unique and transformative? Do you wish to get overseas experience and eventually come back to your original country?

Once you nail down your objective, you need to look at the associated issues. For example, if you wish to migrate, then getting a citizenship/visa in the continent/country of your choice must be first considered. It is not straightforward and it is also not something which is consistent with time.

Second, are you looking for funding or are you self-funded? That will limit your choices to specific universities and groups.

Third, and perhaps, most importantly, you need to identify the area of your choice. Not all universities offer all kinds of research directions. You need to determine what area in AI appeals to you. In fact, this should be the motivation for your PhD and determine the objective. Anything else and you will surely struggle to do a good job with your research.

In my personal opinion, you must also consider you compatibility with potential supervisors. You must align your objectives with the expectations with him or her. Only then will your journey be smooth. You say you want to do tech entrepreneurship. Not all research groups will enable you to do that. Most of the groups consist of academicians whose main goal is to publish and grow in their field, not pursue business opportunities by developing technologies.

This is a serious business and one must give a lot of thought to it. If you want to be a tech entrepreneur, then do you really wish to wait for 3 years (7 years in US) while doing a PhD? PhD will entail a number of things which does not align with that goal. Would you be motivated enough to do it?

As you answer these questions, you will find that choice between continents is too high level a question to think about.